# I can't seem to break out of my While loop even when it is False?

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

I am writing Python code for the game Tic Tac Toe, however I have stumbled upon a hurdle already and can't seem to break out of a While loop:

```
print("Welcome to Tic Toe!")

Player1_Tag=input("Player 1: Choose between X and 0: ")

while Player1_Tag != "X" or Player1_Tag != "0":
    print("Invalid input")
    Player1_Tag=input("Player 1: Choose between X and 0: ")
else:
    if Player1_Tag=="X":
        Player2_Tag="0"
    else:
        Player2_Tag="X"
```

When I run this the program, it asks if I want to be "X" or "0" - if i choose '#' for example I get "Invalid input" and it asks me again in which case I choose "X" but it again gives me "Invalid input" and asks me again.. which is of course not what I want. I am confused as I don't understand why the loop keeps going even though I choose a valid input?

I have tried putting a "break" in the while loop but the loop breaks out if I choose an invalid input twice consecutively.. which is not what I want, I want it to ask me again for the third time, fourth time until I get it right.

Comment: You want `and` instead of `or`

Comment: To clarify @Sorath's comment: `while Player1_Tag != "X" and Player1_Tag != "0":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Player1_Tag != "X" or Player1_Tag != "0"` will *always* be true.

Consider 3 possibilities:

1. If `Player1_Tag == "X"`, then `Player1_Tag != "0"`
2. If `Player1_Tag == "0"`, then `Player1_Tag != "X"`
3. If `Player1_Tag` is anything else, it is neither `"X"` nor `"0"`.

A clearer way to write this would be `while Player1_Tag not in ("X","0"):`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by a logic error in the condition you're testing in your loop. You're currently testing `Player1_Tag != "X" or Player1_Tag != "0"`, which is always `True`, regardless of what `Player1_Tag` is. If the variable is equal to one of the strings, it will be not-equal to the other. Since you're joining the two comparisons with `or`, you'll never exit the loop.

You need to either join the pieces of your test with `and` instead of `or` (`Player1_Tag != "X" and Player1_Tag != "0"`), or negate the comparisons (by changing `!=` to `==`) and do a negation of the whole expression: `not (Player1_Tag == "X" or Player1_Tag == "0")`. By [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), those are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've used `or` when you should have used `and`

If `Player1_Tag` is equal to `0` It's at the same time not equal to `X`
And `or` checks if either is `True'